# Cannot destructure property 'token' of 'req.cookie' as it is undefined. Nodejs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, cookies, mern

This is my code where I save the token into a cookie

```
    const sendToken = (user, statusCode, res) => {
        const token = user.getJWTToken();
        //options for cookie
        const options ={
            expires: new Date(
                Date.now + process.env.COOKIE_EXPIRE * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
            ),
            httpOnly: true
        };
    
        res.status(statusCode).cookie('token', token, options).json({
            success: true,
            user,
            token
        });
    };

module.exports = sendToken;
```

I check in postman and the cookie has been saved
[image]

But later on when I try to get it in this function:

```
exports.isAuthenticatedUser = catchAsyncErrors( async(req,res,next) => {
    const { token } = req.cookie;

    if(!token){
        return next(new ErrorHandler("Please Login to Access this Resource.", 401));
    }

    const decodedData = JsonWebTokenError.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);

    req.user = await User.findById(decodedData.id);
    next();
});
```

It given the error **Cannot destructure property 'token' of 'req.cookie' as it is undefined.**

I'm new to Nodejs so I was following a tutorial. So I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Should that be `req.cookies`? https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.cookies

Comment: But when i console.log(req). It has a field ```cookie:'token:somevalue'```

Comment: `Cookie` is the HTTP header - you can get the raw value for that by using `req.get('Cookie')`. `req.cookies` gives you a pre-parsed version of that value and is output by the [cookie-parser middleware](https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-parser).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `cookieParser` (from the way you are setting the cookie), try changing this:

```
const { token } = req.cookie;
```

To this:

```
const { token } = req.cookies['token']
```

Comment: This did work, thanks. But shouldn't it deconstruct it without the ```['token']``` added to it? Could you explain why I needed to write that?

Comment: Glad to help. Yes it should deconstruct it, when I was going through your code I  did it with the bracket notation and left your deconstruction. So, you can either just do `const { token } = req.cookies;` or `const  token  = req.cookies['token']` (or with the dot notation) and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you use something like `cookie-parser` and that your user is logged in.

You can also see cookies in the postman cookie section. See below - if the cookie is not there, then you have to generate a cookie first.

[image: Postman screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

const token=req.cookies['token'] worked for me

Comment: This does not provide an original answer to the question. and duplicates the one of @perthos. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34492992)